# HPE switch blocks OpenVPN connections

Tags: networking, switch, hp

When my PC is plugged-in on an HPE switch*, I can not connect to **some** VPN servers that are located somewhere at the Internet and are listening at the default port 1194/UDP. I can connect to some others.

*: HPE OfficeConnect Switch 1820 48G J9981A, HP Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to the WebUI of HPE, go to Security -> Advanced Security, uncheck "Prevent UDP Blat Attack", Click apply, Click "save configuration"